# Why doesn't UX Stack Exchange have a mobile app for iOS and Android to broaden audience

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, accessibility

This may be marked down at an astronomical rate - but here goes...

I find myself viewing UX stack exchange quite regularly on my iOS device, when on the go and thinking a downloadable app would be of benefit for 'widening the net' of users who want to access the forum ad-hoc from anywhere, thus increasing the chances of askers getting the very best answers in return, Transparent benefits would include faster access and a broader audience.

This is not opinion based, but more can see potential benefits fomr this being developed, thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 7):

**We do!**

[An iOS app was released two weeks ago.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/)

The [Android app was released in January 2014.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/)

Comment: Any plans for a Windows Phone app? Though honestly IE on the phone is quite competent.